# How to perform a HTTP delete? All I am given is the URL

Tags: java, web-services, http, http-delete

I'm just a starter in java and would like to know how to make a HTTP Delete call to a URL.
Any small piece of code or reference material would be very helpful.

I know that the question would sound very simply, but I am in urgent of this information.

Comment: Do you know how to make an HTTP GET call to a URL?

Comment: No, is it necessary to make a get call before we perform a delete??

Comment: I mean that if you know how to do a GET, then you know how to do a DELETE.

Comment: Can you post some code,so that can help find solution for your problem?

Comment: HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); DeleteMethod del = new DeleteMethod(url); client.setConnectionTimeout(8000); client.executeMethod(del); del.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml" );

Comment: I had tried the above method, I know how to use the Get method and that works fine without any issues. I am able to retrive the values on the URL using the GET method

Answer (score 1):

DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS methods are restricted by most of the servers.  Here is good discussion about this topic in SO.
[Are the PUT, DELETE, HEAD, etc methods available in most web browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers)

Comment: Additionally, some servers don't accept DELETE requests with a request-body.  So it's not just browsers we need to be weary of.  +1

Answer (score 1):

Actually sending HttpDelete is similar to HttpGet, first you will build the url with all parameters and then just execute the request, the following code is tested.

```
    StringBuilder urlBuilder = new StringBuilder(Config.SERVER)
            .append("/api/deleteInfo?").append("id=")
            .append(id);
    urlBuilder.append("&people=").append(people).toString();

    try {

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpDelete httpDelete = new HttpDelete(urlBuilder.toString());
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpDelete);
        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        final String response = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        Log.d(TAG, "content = " + response);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "content = " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.gc();
    }
```

Comment: can you tell me where to put headres? like BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Restlet](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/21-restlet/318-restlet/320-restlet.html). Its a good client API.Or you can do as following

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/resource");
HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
httpCon.setRequestProperty(
    "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );
httpCon.setRequestMethod("DELETE");
httpCon.connect();
httpCon.getInputStream()
```

Comment: Hi, the above method doesn't work it returns 'Bad Request'. I have tried even the DeleteMethod delete = new DeleteMethod('http://www.example.com/resource'); it doesn't for this too.

Comment: Could you please let me know how to execute the 
DeleteMethod delete = new DeleteMethod('http://example.com/resource');

Comment: HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
      DeleteMethod del = new DeleteMethod(url);
      client.setConnectionTimeout(8000);
      client.executeMethod(del);
      del.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml" );

Comment: I had tried the above method, I know how to use the Get method and that works fine without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can call like this :

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.abcd.com/blog");
HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpConnection.setDoOutput(true);
httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );
httpConnection.setRequestMethod("DELETE");
httpConnection.connect();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the Apache HttpClient, it provides an API for all HTTP methods (GET, PUT, DELETE, POST, OPTIONS, HEAD, and TRACE).

For a sample look here: http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/methods/delete.
API reference is here: http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/index.html

Cheers